# Date and time If not IsEmpty to empty cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have that code in VBA, it's fill cell by actual date and time in double-click but i can't do second if to don't rewritting exist cell with date.
Here is code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A5000")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Formula = Date + Time
    Else
        If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
            MsgBox "You can not overwrite date!"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

How i can repire this code to dont overwrite exist cell with date?
Sry for my english:)
Regards.

Comment: do you want to overwrite with now if something else is in the cell?

Comment: If someone click to cell with exist date i want display error message by MsgBox - You cant overwrite Date!

Comment: Hm, just guessing, but maybe you want to pass `Cancel` by reference and use it in calling sub?

Comment: what other precautions are you using to lock the cell and prevent the user from just typing something or deleting the current value?

Comment: Please write a clear question, explaining what you've tried. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MichałTurczyn = the Cancel is to halt in-cell editing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need this...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A5000")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        If Not IsDate(Target) Then
            Target.Formula = Now
        Else
            MsgBox "You can not overwrite date!"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it is! 
Thank you :)

Comment: I'd move `Cancel = True` inside the `Else` clause

Comment: @DisplayName Why would you want to do that? If you place `Cancel = True` in the `Else` block, the cell will go into the `Edit` mode if it places a date time stamp in the cell which doesn't make any sense. Please explain if you have any particular reason to do so.

Comment: @sktneer, it's out of a guess of mine: I guessed that the double click would be sort of a short cut to let user input a date giving him current date as default value

Comment: Well, maybe you need to try that code and let me know if it needs any tweak. :)